# How does Link::SetLinearVel(const math::Vector3 &_vel) achieve the link velocity?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I thought that it would set non-physically real velocity to the link. But if I connect two objects -- A and B, and assign a velocity to object A using this method, the velocity inside the simulation seems to change with physical properties of the object B. For example mass, friction or the spring stiffness of the connection. Is there a way how to achieve a perfect velocity match?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23856/how-does-link::setlinearvel(const-math::vector3-&_vel)-achieve-the-link-velocity?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So the velocity is directly assign as the object variable `lvel`, but on every step the [ODE physics engine](https://bitbucket.org/odedevs/ode/src/default/ode/src/quickstep.cpp) computes the movement of the object by not only taking this velocity, but also considering the forces acting on the object

```
rhscurr[RHS__L_MIN + j] = -(b->facc[dV3E__AXES_MIN + j] * body_invMass + b->lvel[dV3E__AXES_MIN + j] * stepsizeRecip);
```

where `b` is the body (object), `b->facc` is the accumulated forces and `b->lvel` is the assigned linear velocity. That's why the object does not maintain the assigned velocity if there is another massive body being pulled by it.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0